# tkinter filedialog - how to get directory of selected file?

Tags: python, tkinter, directory, filesystems

How can I get folder where is stored file selected from tkinter `filedialog`?

I want make something such this:

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
filename = fd.askopenfilename()
print(filename.directory)
```

Comment: Use `os.path.dirname(filename)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `os.path.dirname` for that.

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import os

filename = fd.askopenfilename()
print(os.path.dirname(filename))
```